# Is financial visualization broken? Can you run any of these examples or InteractiveTradingChart[] at all?

Tags: bugs, visualization, finance

I can't run anything relevant to financial visualization in my mathematica installation, i found [these](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/financial-visualization/) interesting example but anything that use the trading chart is kind of broken.

EDIT:
I'll add a screenshot of the output of the basic example for InteractiveTradingChart
[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information - like what error messages do you get, what do you see - what command are you executing - what is your mathematica version & os etc. ... personally I try the first example for `TradingChart` in the documentation `data = FinancialData["IBM", "OHLCV", {{2009, 5, 1}, {2010, 4, 30}}];` and it gets stuck on `Downloading 5 of 5 values....` so maybe the server is having problems right now.

Comment: Whatever the problem, it seems to have been fixed.

Comment: @flinty Just using that part of the example does not work for me. `data = FinancialData["IBM", "OHLCV", {{2009, 5, 1}, {2010, 4, 30}}];` yelds the error:
`TimeSeries::invstrct: The data TemporalData[TimeSeries,{{StructuredArray[<<1>>]},{TemporalData UniformTimeSpecification[{3450124800,3450384000,3450470400,<<45>>,3456172800,3456432000,<<202>>}]},<<4>>,{ValueDimensions->1,DateFunction->Automatic,ResamplingMethod->{Interpolation,InterpolationOrder->1},TemporalRegularity->True}},<<4>>,11.1] is not a structurally valid TemporalData object.`

Comment: zurg, what version are you running? Your screenshot says 12.2, or is this actually 12.1.1? This is valuable information to include in your OP

Comment: I'm on 12.1.0 @CATrevillian Thanks for asking.
Do you think an upgrade to 12.1.1 would be relevant to fix this problem?

Comment: @zurg that cannot be known for certainty without testing to see if that will fix it. I’ll see if it works on mine, though. Will let you know.

Comment: @CATrevillian can you give me an update? Did you manage to test it on your installation? Thanks

Comment: updated to 12.1.1 Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It was indeed a bug](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2057346?p_p_auth=5UbenhSh) and now it has been fixed!